# Как сохранить себе svg анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animation

Вот на этом [сайте](https://www.digitalsolutions.dev) есть крутая анимация на главной странице, как её можно сохранить себе, что бы потом в дальнейшем использовать?
[image: Текст]
Возможно ли вообще взять с сайта примера эту svg, отредактировать под себя, кое что удалить и выложить на своём сайте? С обычной svg было бы понятно, но как сохранить и анимирование?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: там lotti это дополнение к adobe animate, помещают внутрь дашборда в adobe animate и включают последовательно или выключают какие то компоненты ... после того как результат удовлетворил сохрняют на жёсткий диск .. при сохранении так же экспортируется некий json который и есть основным так как и файл который читает и запускает этот json  то есть lotti.js